# How do I create a Rails form for batch creation of records each containing an Active Storage attachment that uploads directly to S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a Ruby on Rails application which permits creating records with Direct Uploads using Active Storage as described here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads

Everything works fine. Now I'd like to have a way to set up batch record creation also using direct uploads but can't seem to figure out the best approach.

Let's just say I have a model called HomeMovie with various attributes and a video attachment. I'd like to be able to fill out multiple HomeMovie forms one after the next, click submit once, and start the upload with large attachments for each and be able to walk away. With my current setup, doing one at a time, with these large attachments takes too long and needs constant babysitting. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm using Rails 5.2.3

Answer (score 0):

What about setting up some kind of micro-service/jobs using Sidekiq that allows you to essentially que up videos as individual jobs?

Essentially your logic would que up async jobs to handle the processing of the attachments; then it's just a matter of properly setting up the loop.

LOOP EXAMPLE

```
def bulk_insert(videos) #with videos being an array or collection
  videos.each do |vid|
   #do whatever processing and record creation, then
   VideoProcessJob.perform_async(vid["attachment_key"])
  end
end
```

JOB EXAMPLE

```
class VideoProcessJob(video_attachment)
  #assumes a service/module for processing the videos
  VideoProcessor.new(video_attachment).process_video_attachment_logic
end
```

Comment: My problem is more to do with how to submit a form with multiple records that also uses direct uploads during submission. After the records are saved, using a post processing job like you suggest should work. Any ideas on how to get the direct upload js to work this way? Currently, clicking submit on the form initializes the direct upload, and doesn't actually submit the record for saving until the attachments are finished uploading to S3. I appreciate your suggestion.